# Times New Roman with PdfLatex

Tags: fonts, pdftex

i'm  writing a report with Latex i need to use Times New Roman font type but i couldn't find an easy way.
I used the \usepackage{times} package but it looks diffrent do  you have any other idea ?

Comment: Also, if you're using xelatex or lualatex (both of which output pdf by default), the answer would be "use `fontspec`" and just tell it to load Times New Roman by name.

Answer (score 0):

There is no actual Times New Roman font in native LaTeX.
The best alternative you can get is using:

```
\usepackage{mathptmx} % http://ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx
```

Comment: Okay thnx any way

Comment: There are much better alternatives to `mathptmx`.